# App comparison using androguard

Tags: android, androguard

I am working on android malware detection. So I have used Androguard for app analysis(in windows 7). But when I use androsim.py for app comparison it gives "MemoryError".
Command Used is :

```
androsim.py -i <apk1> <apk2> -c ZLIB -n
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Directly download executable file [Androsim.exe](https://code.google.com/archive/p/androguard/downloads) and run this tool to compare.

and run this command :

```
androsim.exe -i <path_of_first_apk> <path_of_second_apk> -c ZLIB -n
```